# is their any way to change source file paths of css and js while page load if file is not found at specified path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose minified css/js files are stored in separate folder so if a particular minified file is not found then how can we change src/href path with non minified file using js or jquery or any other way? ex:

```
<link href="path/to/minifiedfile.css">
.
.
.
<script scr="path/to/minifiedfile.js">
.
.
.
this files are not found, is their any way to replace those paths to nonminified files with jquery or javascript

i have tried with js onerror but need to mention onerror function call in all link and scripts tag so any other way using jquery?

    <html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="path/to/minified.css" onerror="this.href=myfunction(this.href);">
        <link href="path/to/minified.css" onerror="this.href=myfunction(this.href);">
        <link href="path/to/minified.css" onerror="this.href=myfunction(this.href);">
        .
        .
        .
        <script scr="path/to/minified.js" onerror="this.src=myfunction(this.src);">
        <script scr="path/to/minified.js" onerror="this.src=myfunction(this.src);">
        <script scr="path/to/minified.js" onerror="this.src=myfunction(this.src);">
        <script scr="path/to/minified.js" onerror="this.src=myfunction(this.src);">
        .
        .
        .
        <script>
            function myfunction(link) {
            var nonminifiedpath = link.replace('/minified', '');
            return nonminifiedpath;
        }
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

onerror="this.href=myfunction(this.href);
this need to be used in every link tag so any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop on `querySelectorAll` for pure JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("script").forEach(e => e.onerror = myfunction(e.src));
document.querySelectorAll("link").forEach(e => e.onerror = myfunction(e.href));
```

jQuery version:

```
$("script").each((_, e) => e.error(() => myfunction(e.src)));
$("link").each((_, e) => e.error(() => myfunction(e.href)));
```